# Fortran interface to itself produces annoying error

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This problem has been around for a few years, but I never heard of a good solution to it.

If a Fortran subroutine includes a module with an interface to itself

```
subroutine stuff(nz,z,dt)
  use allinterfaces
  ...
```

an error occurs

> Error: 'stuff' of module 'allinterfaces', imported at (1), is also the name of the current program unit

To fix it I have to declare

```
subroutine stuff(nz,z,dt)
  use allinterfaces, except_this_one => stuff
  ...
```

This is absurd behavior and annoying since I like to include all interfaces in a module. It would be helpful if this was not a compile error, or at least there should be an `except_itself`

The compiler I am using is gfortran version 4.8.2 (GCC), but I doubt this is the compiler's fault.

Does anyone understand the rational behind this behavior, or a more practical solution?

The compiler could use this information to check whether the interface defined in the module matches the actual subroutine.  So it's two levels worse than it could be. Ignoring the information is a missed opportunity; treating it as an error is counterproductive.

Comment: I have the same question... Because of this, the interface block does not work for checking whether the definition itself is correct or not ><

Comment: If you have a subroutine which uses a module which contains an interface block which defines the interface of that subroutine, then it certainly isn't the compiler's fault.  What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @francescalus Though I don't know OP's case, I am simply interested in why the "standards committee" prohibited this (because there seems to be no good reason to me). One scenario in which this is useful is that one invokes a routine from a huge old-Fortran-style package (which is not contained in modules) and one wants to ensure the consistency of relevant subroutine calls (particularly newly added ones). In my experience, some electronic structure code, which has been still actively developed, is written in this style (it even relies on a huge number of COMMON blocks... hmm).

Comment: @roygvib The question and your point (which is covered in the answer) are reasonable (although I find the question too "ranty" for a +1).  This prohibition, though, goes back to F90 so any detail beyond "the standard says so" will be hard to find.  If I had lots of external program units where an `only` clause on a use statement was too cumbersome I'd probably be more worried.

Answer (score 9):

This behavior is specified by the Fortran standard. The standards committee discussed relaxing the restriction, termed "interface to self", but ultimately rejected it. I don't remember the specifics. Since the standard forbids it, compilers are required to be able to diagnose it and most do by default.

You'd encounter this problem only when trying to incrementally update an F77-style program to use explicit interfaces. I'll note that Intel Fortran, and maybe gfortran as well, has a feature that will automatically check such interfaces for you (in ifort it's -warn interface).

Perhaps the better approach is to put your procedures in modules.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the recent Fortran standards have become obsessed with modules, which alienates traditional Fortran programmers. Why do we have to wrap everything in modules now? 

For gfortran I can only find -Wimplicit-interface and -Wimplicit-procedure as relevant compiler options.

Comment: It is a relatively straightforward process to shift procedures into modules, and makes it so much easier to diagnose problems caused by calling a subroutine or function incorrectly. I would contend that what you're trying to do in your original post is related to an obsession with a deprecated style of coding.