# How do you specify a module variable as a part of dummy argument declaration inside an interface block?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have a subroutine `sub_x` defined as

```
subroutine sub_x(n, a)
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  use mod_a, only : m
  implicit none
  integer(c_long), intent(in) :: n
  real(c_double), intent(in) :: a(1:m)
  .
  .
  .
  rest of the codes
  .
  .
```

That is, `sub_x` depends on a module variable `m` as an extent of its array argument. Now, in a separate file, the interface block of `sub_x` goes as follows

```
module mod_x
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  
  interface
     subroutine sub_x(n, a)
       import :: c_long, c_double, m
       integer(c_long), intent(in) :: n
       real(c_double), intent(in) :: a(1:m)
     end
  end interface
end module mod_x
```

And any procedure calling `sub_x` will have a `use mod_x` statement. When trying to compile the file containing module `mod_x`, `file_x.f90` with `ifort -c file_x.f90`  I got error saying "IMPORT-name must be the name of an entity in the host scoping unit.  [m]" showing that the compiler was not able to resolve `m`. It may be able to resolve `c_long` and `c_double` because of the presence of `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding` in `mod_x` definition, but I may be wrong. Adding `use mod_a, only : m` in `mod_x` definition may solve the issue, but that means `mod_x` will depend on `mod_a` and I try to avoid dependency between modules.

One way that seems to work is to move the interface block to a plain text file, say `interface_x.f90`, and add an `include "interface_x.f90"` line in any procedure calling `sub_x`. But I try to avoid using this method because I have tens of external subroutines and it's better to have the interfaces of all of them in a single file. If I were to use this, just about any procedure having an `include "interface_x.f90"` will have to have `use mod_a, only : m` even though it doesn't need `m`. What's the solution?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your code is not even the ancient Fortran 90 but at least Fortran 2003.

Comment: "I try to avoid dependency between modules": there _is_ a dependency here. Avoiding writing `use mod_a` doesn't make that dependency go away.

Comment: @VladimirF Sorry about that, I am not very informed about the differences between Fortran standards.

Comment: At first, I actually use the include line method but then I realize that if I collect the interfaces of all external procedures in a single file, there will be problems arises such as the interface of a given procedure being included in the definition of that same procedure which creates compile error. I thought this was not a problem. So I swicthed to module method.

Comment: This collection problem sounds to be related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32161560/3157076).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Since its mentioned in the answer of that question, in case you are wondering why I don't put the procedures under contains statement of a module (hence making the interface implicit), it's because I am doing mixed programming between c++ and fortran where some subroutines are called both in fortran codes and c++ codes. I might be wrong but in the past when I placed a fortran subroutine in a module, it cannot be called through the default way from c++ side. Not sure if that was just me not knowing the alternative ways.

Comment: If you are worried about calling from C (where indeed procedures in a module and outside a module are handled differently) then you can look at the standardized C interoperability [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding], using `subroutine sub_x(n,a) bind(c)` approach. In that tag you will see many examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to use an `import` statement to make an entity accessible in an interface block. It is one way, and in some cases the only way. This is not one of those cases.

The `import` statement controls accessibility of entities from the host scope of a scoping block (such as an interface block).  In the (simplified) case of the question

```
module mod_x
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  
  interface
     subroutine sub_x()
       import :: c_long
     end
  end interface
end module mod_x
```

the import statement makes the entity `c_long` from the module scope accessible in the interface specification of `sub_x`.  That entity is itself available in the module scope because it is use associated from the module `iso_c_binding`.

Exactly the same entity is made accessible in the interface specification by

```
module mod_x
  interface
     subroutine sub_x()
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_long
     end
  end interface
end module mod_x
```

This is much as in the actual subroutine specification of `sub_x`.  `m` can be made accessible in the same way:

```
module mod_x
  interface
     subroutine sub_x(n, a)
       use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_long, c_double
       use mod_a, only : m
       integer(c_long), intent(in) :: n
       real(c_double), intent(in) :: a(1:m)
     end
  end interface
end module mod_x
```

(Or equivalently by combining an `import` with `use mod_a` in the module scope.)

Note that this is a module dependency whichever way you write it: `mod_x` depends on `mod_a` because the interface specified in `mod_x` has a characteristic determined by an entity in `mod_a`.

Comment: Basically, I am indecisive as to which one is closer to the fortran programming best practices, between having inter-module dependencies or lots of plain, include-line-intended, files each containing interface of a single procedure.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with having modules dependent on modules. Clearly one has to avoid designs which lead to _circular_ or _spaghetti_ dependency. At the most absurd this spartanism leads to the wholly unproductive avoidance of even `use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding`.

Comment: So, using ``use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding`` is to be avoided?

Comment: Gosh, no. Use `iso_c_binding` whenever you need to. What I meant was that `use iso_c_binding` gives a module dependency and one certainly doesn't want to avoid that through a principle of avoiding dependencies. Well structured code can easily include module dependencies (intrinsic, own, or third-party) if carefully designed, documented and supported by the build process.

Comment: You could remove the module dependency by making the dummy argument `a` assumed shape `a(:)` rather than explicit shape `a(m)`, or having `m` another dummy argument, but this changes the meaning of things.